# What do ellipses mean in a Coq proof?

Tags: coq

Here is a proof that appears in this online course https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/StlcProp.html#lab222.

```
Proof with eauto.
  remember (@empty ty) as Gamma.
  intros t t' T HT. generalize dependent t'.
  induction HT;
       intros t' HE; subst Gamma; subst;
       try solve [inversion HE; subst; auto].
  - (* T_App *)
    inversion HE; subst...
    (* Most of the cases are immediate by induction,
       and [eauto] takes care of them *)
    + (* ST_AppAbs *)
      apply substitution_preserves_typing with T11...
      inversion HT1...
Qed.
```

What do the ellipses do in this line?
`apply substitution_preserves_typing with T11...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ellipses apply a certain predefined tactic. In this proof, it's `eauto` since the proof started with `Proof with eauto`. See the [reference manual](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:cmd.proof-with) for more.